# Error running timer (wrong-number-of-arguments equals 3)

Tags: timers, error

I am trying to automatically change my Emacs theme according to time set ([Thanks to answer provided by Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14760833/5727578)).

My code looks like this:

```lisp
(setq emacs-curr-theme nil)
(setq emacs-light-theme 'faff)
(setq emacs-dark-theme 'atom-one-dark)

(defun emacs-synchronize-theme ()

  (let ((hour nil) (now nil))
    (progn (setq hour 
        (string-to-number 
            (substring (current-time-string) 11 13)))
    (if (member hour (number-sequence 7 13))
        (setq now emacs-light-theme)
        (setq now emacs-dark-theme))

    (if (equal now emacs-curr-theme now)
        nil
        (progn
          (setq emacs-curr-theme now)
          (load-theme emacs-curr-theme t))))))

(defun emacs-set-theme ()
  ;; Load theme only when using GUI
  (when (display-graphic-p)
      (run-with-timer 0 900 'emacs-synchronize-theme)))
```

When I am calling the function `emacs-set-theme` from my `init.el`, I am getting this error -

```
Error running timer 'emacs-synchronize-theme': (wrong-number-of-arguments equal 3)
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong here. I have checked documentation for `run-with-timer`, but unable to figure out the problem by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is:

`(equal now emacs-curr-theme now)`

As `equal` takes two arguments, not three.

I used <kbd>M-x</kbd> `toggle-debug-on-error` before running your code
to find that quickly:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments equal 3)
  (equal now emacs-curr-theme now)
  (if (equal now emacs-curr-theme now) nil (progn (setq emacs-curr-theme now) (load-theme emacs-curr-theme t)))
  (progn (setq hour (string-to-number (substring (current-time-string) 11 13))) (if (member hour (number-sequence 7 13)) (setq now emacs-light-theme) (setq now emacs-dark-theme)) (if (equal now emacs-curr-theme now) nil (progn (setq emacs-curr-theme now) (load-theme emacs-curr-theme t))))
  (let ((hour nil) (now nil)) (progn (setq hour (string-to-number (substring (current-time-string) 11 13))) (if (member hour (number-sequence 7 13)) (setq now emacs-light-theme) (setq now emacs-dark-theme)) (if (equal now emacs-curr-theme now) nil (progn (setq emacs-curr-theme now) (load-theme emacs-curr-theme t)))))
  emacs-synchronize-theme()
  apply(emacs-synchronize-theme nil)
  timer-event-handler([t 24378 24806 149715 900 emacs-synchronize-theme nil nil 39000])
```